# How to tell whether the object of the verb should have al before it or take in the -n form

Tags: grammar

For example: *"diras al vi"* vs. *"ŝatas vin"*.

I also heard that sometimes both versions are allowed but not always.

Answer (score 3):

The linguistic term is [case government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_government) (*rekcio* in Esperanto) which refers to how non-subject nouns and pronouns connect to a verb.

There are two major roles such a noun/pronoun can have: either it is the direct object of the action ("I like **you**") or it is the recipient or beneficiary of an action ("I talk to **you**").

### object

When having the role of a direct object a noun/pronoun and its possible adjective attributes are in accusative – taking the ending *-n* – in Esperanto.

- *Mi ŝatas vi**n**.*
- *Mi vidis nigra**n** kato**n**.*

The accusative case is quite likely the most common case – besides the base, nominative case – in languages with a case system. (See a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnF1ycgelUY) for a quick introduction to cases.)

Other languages may have additional cases (e.g. partitive in Finnish), pre- or postpositions (*lo* in Spanish, を in Japanese) or just rely on the word order (English).

### recipient or beneficiary

While some languages use a grammatical case (often dative) for marking a recipient or beneficiary of the verb's action (e.g. German: *Ich gab dem Mann das Buch*: I gave the book to the man.), Esperanto mostly uses the preposition *al* for this purpose.

- *Mi diris **al vi**.*
- *Mi donis la libron **al la viro**.*

Compare this to English which relies on the word order ("I sent you a letter") or uses the preposition "to" ("I sent a letter to you").

### either way?

There is a handful of verbs with which a noun/pronoun can be interpreted to be an object or a recipient.

- *Mi helpas **vin**.* : I help you (considered to be the object of the action)
- *Ĉu Esperanto helpas **al mi** lerni la francan?* : Does Esperanto help me to learn French? (considered to be the recipient of the action)

Note, that here in the latter case *min* is also possible, while *mi  helpas al vi* is rarely used.

### how to know?

If one's native language has accusative for a direct object, accusative in Esperanto is often a no-brainer. Otherwise you just simply have to learn, which may sound harsh, but let me assure you that quite quickly you develop a sense whether we are talking about an object or a recipient.

Here helps a good dictionary, like [PIV 2020](https://vortaro.net/), which tells whether a verb is transitive or not (e.g. in PIV marked *(tr)* for transitive and *(ntr)* for intransitive), i.e. whether it takes a direct object or not. Furthermore a good dictionary should provide information about case government and have some examples of use.